# In Python, does a function capture variables created after the function is defined?

Tags: python, closures

I am trying to better understand closures. Examples 1 - 3 make sense to me according to my understanding, but I think it must be incorrect since example 4 does not make sense to me.

## Example 1

```py
def f():
    print(x)
x=1
f() # prints 1
```

At the time `f()` is defined, `x` does not exist, but that's fine. It will be looked up when `f()` is invoked, at which point `x` exists.

## Example 2

```py
y=2
def g():
    print(y)
g() # prints 2
```

This is a closure. When `g()` is defined, `y` exists and `g()` captures a reference to it. If I were to change the value of `y` after defining `g()`, this change would be reflected when `g()` is invoked. As far as I know, this does not involve a closure.

## Example 3

```py
def h():
    x=3
    def i():
        print(x)
    return i
j=h()
j() # prints 3
```

This just shows that a closure retains a reference to variables even after they go out of scope. Once `h()` returns, I cannot refer to directly `x` since it has gone out of scope, but `j()` retains a reference to it.

## Example 4

```py
def k():
    def l():
        print(x)
    x=4
    return l
m=k()
m() # prints 4
```

This one is confusing to me. I would think (as I claimed in example 1) that `l()` is not a closure, so it doesn't retain a reference to `x`; it would just attempt to look up `x` when invoked. But, in fact, when we invoke it via `m()`, `x` is printed even though it has gone out of scope. Does this mean that `f()` from example 1 was also a closure? It seems surprising that a function could capture variables created after its definition. Unless its wrong to say that it captures variables per se. Is it more accurate to say that it captures the "environment" or "scope" in which it is defined?

Comment: This [YouTube](https://youtu.be/jXugs4B3lwU) video by `mCoding` explains *everything*.

Comment: *"Does this mean that f() from example 1 was also a closure?"*: yes

Comment: @quamrana Oh wow, the "level 2" section where he explains that assigning to a variable *even in a code path that isn't executed* changes which variable is looked up blew my mind and is the key to understanding this. Thank you.

Comment: pythontutor is great for showing how such code snippets work; just paste code and visualize step-by-step [link](https://pythontutor.com/python-debugger.html#mode=edit)

Answer (score 1):

As per question:

```py
def k():
    def l():
        print(x)
    x=4
    return l
m=k()
m() # prints 4
```

A nested function has access to outer function locals. In this case, `x=4` is a variable local to function `k()`. Hence, inner function `l()` also has access to this same information.

*Further research*: I would suggest to fire up the `python` REPL and try this out in a terminal window.

```py
>>> def k():
...   a = 1
...   def l():
...     print(a, b)
...     print(locals())
...   b = 2
...   print(locals())
...   return l
... 
>>> k()
{'l': <function k.<locals>.l at 0x10140bec0>, 'a': 1, 'b': 2}
<function k.<locals>.l at 0x10140bec0>
>>> k()()
{'l': <function k.<locals>.l at 0x101414180>, 'a': 1, 'b': 2}
1 2
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The fact that a nested function has access to an outer function's locals isn't the part that confuses me (that's just a straight-forward closure as in my example 3). What confuses me is that it can access even variables that are defined after the inner function is defined. But the mCoding video linked in one of the comments on the OP explains it clearly.

Comment: @master_latch i am not sure I understand where the confusion is. It does not really matter at what point a function is defined (before or after vars are). All that really matters is at what scope (level) and at the point it is called, it has access to those vars (which makes sense, if you think about it).